# Converting Facebook session keys to access tokens

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a web app that allows users to connect Facebook account with their account on my site. When the user decides to connect with Facebook, the app requests `publish_stream` and `offline_access` permissions, and then stores the Facebook `uid` and `session_key` for each user. All this works fine right now.

My problem is migrating to Facebook's new OAuth 2.0 system. I'd like to transform the session keys I have into access tokens. I followed [these instructions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/upgrade#oauth) and everything seemed to work fine; Facebook returned a bunch of access tokens. However, none of them work. When I try to go to a URL such as https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=TOKEN-HERE, I get an error that says "Error validating client".

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I'm under the impression that access tokens work just like session keys in that once I have one, I can use it forever (since I request `offline_access` permissions). Is that correct?

#### Update:

Below are the exact steps I took to convert a session key into an access token, along with the output I got. Hopefully that will help bring my problem to light.

#### Step 1: Convert Session Key to Access Token

Code:

```php
$session_key = '87ebbedf29cc2000a28603e8-100000652996522';
$app = sfConfig::get('app_facebook_prod_api'); // I happen to use Symfony. This gets an array with my Facebook app ID and secret.
$post = array(
  'type' => 'client_cred',
  'client_id' => $app['app_id'],
  'client_secret' => $app['secret'],
  'sessions' => $session_key
);

$options = array(
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/exchange_sessions',
  CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_export(json_decode($result));
```

Output:

```php
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'access_token' => '251128963105|87ebbedf29cc2000a28603e8-100000652996522|Dy8CcJzEX8lYRrJE9Xk1EoW-BW0.',
  )),
)
```

#### Step 2: Test Access Token

Code:

```php
$access_token = '251128963105|87ebbedf29cc2000a28603e8-100000652996522|Dy8CcJzEX8lYRrJE9Xk1EoW-BW0.';
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $access_token,
  CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_export(json_decode($result));
```

Output:

```php
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'error' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'type' => 'OAuthException',
     'message' => 'Error validating client.',
  )),
))
```

Answer (score 1):

From reading your post here is my understanding -

You are tranforming session keys into access keys for each user in your system and storing these keys.

You then test the key using your own page. (Graph.facebook.com/me etc...)

If this is the case

A) You cannot use another users key with your own key. Going to graph.facebook.com would only be valid for the user that the key belongs to and if they were logged in. So for example, if you have my access key you could visit http://graph.facebook.com/YOURID....) but for graph.facebook.com/me to work you would have to be logged in as me.

B) These keys expire every 3 hours (Or there abouts) so it may no longer be valid.

Comment: A is not true. If you read the last instruction on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#authorization, it seems to imply that providing an access token means that the API will act as if you are the person who the token is for. In fact, if you get a token for yourself and then sign out, you can still go to /me.

Comment: Just checked, ok - so when you log in you can access graph.facebook.com/me. But if you log out the key is terminated, the key also expires. Are you sure you are working with an active key when you try testing?

Comment: I can say from experience that the access tokens definitely expire on logout BUT they SHOULDN'T expire if you have offline_access permissions. Are you sure you've acquired offline_access permissions?

Answer (score -5):

The [Platform Upgrade Guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/upgrade) has a section about OAuth 2.0 which includes the instructions for exchanging a `session_key` for an `access_token`. You should use this if you already have stored session keys.

For new users, you should use one of the new SDKs or the [OAuth2 flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) directly which will give you an access token to begin with.

Comment: This is the exact link offered in the question which the poster specified he had read and is following.