# Changes to make in the app for new version of facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

We are using old version of Facebook connect PHP SDK, what changes we need to do to make the app working with the new changes (Currently the app is not working due to FB app version changes)

Comment: What is the version of the SDK you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Update your [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), connection needs change, `getSession()` is no longer available, use `getUser()` instead. Also if you are using too old PHP SDK (before Graph API) then you may have to update some API calling functions.

Overall connection is like below:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '111111111',// your appId here
  'secret' => '1a1a1a1a1a1a1',// your app secret here
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();



} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: We are using SDK version 2.1.1 and connecting using javascript code, can you please give us the list of changes/ steps that we need to do?

Comment: I wrote about PHP SDK, as you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: authentication flow and REST API deprecation

**Long answer**: there have been two major version changes since version 2.1. You should go through the [facebook developer blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog) for clear understanding of changes.

Some of the announcement links below:

1. [Developer Roadmap Update: Moving to OAuth 2.0 + HTTPS](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/)
2. [Upgrade to PHP SDK v3.0.0](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/)
3. [Migrating to OAuth 2.0 update: PHP SDK v.3.1.1](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/)

The new login flow using PHP SDK looks like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(…);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  // proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
} else {
  // proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
}
```

If you are storing session keys at the moment, they will not work anymore. You'll need to migrate to use oauth access tokens. This SO link discusses this process: [Converting Facebook session keys to access tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3259801/410367)

Also, if yours is a canvas app using legacy auth, you'll need to make changes as described on this page: [Migrating to OAuth 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/fb_sig/#migrate)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have few more queries as follows,

Comment: You skipped the 'few more queries' part it seems. You can upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have few more queries as follows,
1) Now we are using PHP SDK version 3.1.1 & did changes in JS code for perms to scope, its working. What changes/ care we need to take for future updates, so that will no affect our site's FB integration functionality.
2) Do we need to set SSL in this new setup?

Comment: SSL is required if you have a canvas app running on FB platform. If it is a website, then it is not required. Subscribe to the [developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) via email, so that you know whenever there is a change in the app platform.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for all response. These changes are working on IE & MOzilla (Firefox) browser properlly. but unable to connect on Chrome, we are using this javascript connection code:

FB.init({appId:appId, status: true,
            cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth      : true,});

Comment: one more query can you please give me the solution to disconnect from Facebook, currently we are doing unset of cookie variable fbsr_api_id

Comment: The question is off topic here, you post a new question with specific queries. Also, consider voting the answer up it answered the question.